# Benefit of Apache Flume

Tags: flume

I am new with Apache Flume.
I understand that Apache Flume can help transport data.

But I still fail to see the ultimate benefit offered by Apache Flume.
If I can configure a software or make a software to send which data goes where, why I need Flume?

Maybe someone can explain a situation that shows Apache Flume's benefit?

Comment: Your thinking is correct. When you try to build such a system that offers components capable of integrating different sources with hdfs and move data reliably, you will end up creating flume. And flume may not fit all your data transfer needs.

Answer (score 0):

Reliable transmission (if you use the file channel):
Flume sends batches of small events. Every time it sends a batch to the next node it waits for acknowledgment before deleting. The storage in the file channel is optimized to allow recovery on crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest benefit that you get out of flume is extensiblity. Basically all components starting from source, interceptor and sink, everything is extensible.

We use flume and read data using custom kakfa source, data is in the form of JSON we parse it in custom kafka source and then pass it on to HDFS sink. It working reliably in 5 of nodes. We extended only kafka source, HDFS sink functionality we got out the box.

At the same time, being from the Hadoop ecosystem, you get great community support and multiple options to use the tools in different ways.